# PHP OOP - Should I use a framework?

Tags: oop, codeigniter, cakephp, php

I've been learning PHP OOP for quite a while and I've loved getting to know the language, finding solutions to problems and so forth.

Although, quite often, people keep recommending different frameworks for me to start using. I can imagine using a framework is more efficient, time effective and so forth but It seems to take quite a lot of the fun out of things.

My next challenge is to create a fully functional tutorial website and blog.

My question is, do you use a PHP framework and should I really start using one?

I was also debating whether to use CodeIgniter or CakePHP...

Comment: If your intention is to learn then you could write your own framework. If you expect someone else to maintain it, then its probably a better idea to use an established one.

Comment: Debates which Framework is better can be daunting. It always depends. For the general idea, I found this read helpful: [When Flat PHP meets Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/from_flat_php_to_symfony2.html) - (this article is not specific to Symfony but outlines a general idea).